# Statistics and random sampling of daily data over a week

Tags: python, statistics, data-science

I'm currently helping a client identify fraud activity using login activity. I've boiled the data down to a specific week and aggregated over day.
for example:

| Date | IP Address | Total Login Attempts | Login Failure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/11/2022 | 1.256.xxx.xxx | 1000 | .5 |
| 7/12/2022 | 1.256.xxx.xxx | 50000 | .2 |
| 7/11/2022 | 1.126.xxx.xxx | 1000 | .5 |

IP address and Date are the primary keys in this table.
Would it be appropriate to randomly sample the Total Login Attempts or Login Failure per day to create a normal distribution to determine outliers in the dataset?
Is there a rule in statistics that would stop this form being effective? i.e. the timeseries components not being independent

Comment: If you're looking for outliers, you can do average and standard deviation, and highlight lines that are some number of standard deviations away from the mean.  95% of entries are within 3 standard deviations of the mean.

Comment: Interesting q. Nothing prevents you from computing z-scores. This cannot tell you nothing.